# JavaScript is not working when upload it to URL

Tags: javascript, html, upload, ftp

I got a java script slide show to work on my computer in my browsers but when I uploaded the files to my ftp site the images become stacked instead of rotating in and out of the frame.

My link to the sample page:

http://www.thaigerkitchen.com/menus.html

If you need the script let me know.

My files are in the correct folders and I think my code is correct.

Can you help me please?

Do I need something special on the ftp site to make my JavaScript work?

Comment: Did you try clearing your cache (ctrl-shift-R on your browser)?

Comment: It looks like `http://www.thaigerkitchen.com/slideShow.js` is missing. You can open a console to see such errors.

Comment: @Antonio. It's javascript, not java. These are totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this instead:

```
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
```

All file names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

Your html references slideShow.js but the filename on the server is slideshow.js -- it works locally because the windows filesystem is not case-sensitive.

Either change your code to slideshow.js all lowercase or fix the filename on the server to be mixed case slideShow.js, as long as they match it will work.

Comment: updated answer to reflect filename case issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your script:

```
<script src="slideShow.js"></script>
```

isn't loading.

Check that you've uploaded it to the root of your site. Also, check that the case is correct.

Comment: Yes I uploaded it to where the index folder is located. Is that the correct location?

Comment: @AntonioMele, yes that's correct however your code says slideShow.js, whereas your file is slideshow.js. Change one to the other and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

When I checked the site out, it said that it failed to load slideShow.js
Are you sure you uploaded the js file? Or is it named incorrectly?

Comment: The name is correct, it worked on my hard drive.

Comment: Did it upload to the server ok? It seems the file name should be slideshow.js.

These names ARE case sensitive!